# Creating constant labeling for x-axis on bar chart

Tags: vba, excel

Beginners question here.  I have a portion of vba script that takes data (depending on previous inputs from a user), and returns a bar chart specific to the data in question.  I am looking for how to augment the code below in order to provide a constant x-axis labeling structure.  I always want the minimum to be 0, and the max to be 5.  Right now, I am getting tailored x-axis labeling dependent upon the returned data.

Some of this may be a jumbled mess, and looking for any ways to make this more efficient or elegant.  Thanks.

```
'CREATE CHART WITH CURRENT
Dim chart_1 As Chart

    'Chart
    If Cells(16, 4).Value = "Data Not Available" Then
        Range("A1").Select
    Else
        Set chart_1 = Charts.Add
        Set chart_1 = chart_1.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="LMC_Model")


        'with statement to expedite typing
        With chart_1
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = scenario & " Scores for " & risk
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered


            'if statement to get correct data for x-axis
            If scenario = current Then
                .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(riskLookupScore).Range("a2:a11, b2:b11"), PlotBy:=xlRows
            ElseIf scenario = shortTerm Then
                .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(riskLookupScore).Range("a2:a11, c2:c11"), PlotBy:=xlRows
            ElseIf scenario = longTerm Then
                .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(riskLookupScore).Range("a2:a11, d2:d11"), PlotBy:=xlRows
            End If

            With .Parent
                .Height = 315
                .Width = 440
                .Top = Range("b26").Top
                .Left = Range("b26").Left
                .Name = "Bar Chart"
            End With
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
With chart_1.
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 5
End With
```

Comment: I appreciate this. It works well and I feel stupid for asking it.  But to clarify, if I want to have a constant step between the axis values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as opposed to 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3...5), can you provide any suggestions.

Comment: try chart_1.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1